# Image created without filetype - need filetype for compression - Angular 2 / Ionic 3

Tags: image, angular, file, ionic-framework, types

I am trying to compress an image client-side (Angular 2/Ionic 3) and When I log the file that is created by the camera, it says:

`"type":null` when it should say `"type":'image/jpeg'`.

I am using the Ionic camera plugin to handle taking a picture or choosing one from the photo library, after that (I assume) the file is created without a type. Every compression tool I have tried has had this problem, and I have run out of options. Is there a way to change the `type` of a `File` object?

Comment: could you add any code snippets that are relevant? Which compression tool are you using?

Comment: i figured out the type problem...but I am running into a new problem...none of the compression tools I use work...I've used ng2-img-max/ng2-img-tools...and I think ionic is having trouble with the fact that it uses a canvas html element to compress...i think i read that for ionic 3 creating a canvas element is a problem

Comment: If you solve your own problem you can answer your own question so that future users with the same issue get help! Also you can edit the question to add relevant information (like the compression tools). Any new problems you can create a new question for :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Blob with this method and made sure to give it image type:

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI, callback): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let byteString = atob(dataURI);
      //console.log(byteString);

      // separate out the mime component
      //let mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

      // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
      let ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      let ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
          ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
      let bb = new Blob([ab], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
      resolve(bb);  

    })
}
```

I used it after reading the contents of the image to base64 like this and got the resulting blob with image type:

```
var readerZ = new FileReader();

  readerZ.onload = (e) => {
    let data = readerZ.result.split(',')[1];
    //console.log(data);
    self.dataURItoBlob(data, null).then(blob => {
```